# Fixed sidebar and main page

Tags: html, css

As I add more content lower on the page, I see that my side bar and main page is not fixed on the page. Basically, I need the side bar to stay where it is as well as the rest of the page (background picture) no matter how much content there is. Hope that's clear enough.
Also, I feel like my code has a lot of useless things added to it. If someone doesn't mind letting me know what that is without changing the way the page looks like that'd be great.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(images/background2.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#backgroundCover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.35;
}

#sideBar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#navigationToggle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 20px 0 60px 10px;
  background-image: url(png/512/navicon-round-white.png);
  background-size: contain;
}

#topmenuicon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 160px 0 60px 10px;
  background-image: url(png/512/ios7-home-white-outline.png);
  background-size: contain;
}

#topmenuicon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url(png/512/ios7-home-outline.png);
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#menuicon1 {
  margin: 60px 0 0 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url(png/512/ios7-person-white-outline.png);
  background-size: contain;
}

#menuicon1:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url(png/512/ios7-person-outline.png);
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#menuicon2 {
  margin: 60px 0 0 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url(png/512/ios7-people-white-outline.png);
  background-size: contain;
}

#menuicon2:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url(png/512/ios7-people-outline.png);
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#menuicon3 {
  margin: 60px 0 0 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url(png/512/ios7-world-white-outline.png);
  background-size: contain;
}

#menuicon3:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url(png/512/ios7-world-outline.png);
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#menuicon4 {
  margin: 60px 0 0 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url(png/512/ios7-gear-white-outline.png);
  background-size: contain;  
}

#menuicon4:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url(png/512/ios7-gear-outline.png);
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Noam's Website</title>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="backgroundCover"></div>
      <div id="sideBar">
        <div id="navigationToggle"></div>
        <div id="topmenuicon"></div>
        <div id="menuicon1"></div>
        <div id="menuicon2"></div>
        <div id="menuicon3"></div>
        <div id="menuicon4"></div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: try `position: fixed` in your css

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:fixed;` to `#sideBar` to fix the sidebar.

Concerning non-moving background, add `background-attachment: fixed;` to the `body`-rule

addition/edit after comment:

And add `margin-left: 50px` to `body` to prevent its content or background being hidden under the fixed sidebar.

Comment: And add padding-left: 50px on your body so the sidebar dont hide the content

Comment: I would instead choose `margin-left: 50px` - that way the background won't go under the sidebar, which it does with the padding